# Random Distribution Question

Tags: probability

If a question refers to "random distribution," is it implied that have an equal probability of occurring?

For example, if we are two distribute $3$ indistinguishable balls into $2$ distinguishable urns, do

$(0, 3)$, $(1, 2)$, $(2, 1)$, and $(3, 0)$ have an equal probability of happening, or do the $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$ cases have a three times as likely chance happening as the other two?

Context: Ryan has $5$ pieces of taffy and $6$ pieces of gum, which he randomly
distributes to three boys all at once. If each boy ends up with at least one piece of
each sweet (taffy and gum), what is the probability that a boy ends up with more
pieces of taffy but fewer pieces of gum than each of the other boys?

Comment: It depends on context.  In your particular example, physical considerations may suggest there could be $8$ equally likely elements of the sample space but, because of the balls being indistinguishable, there are four possible observations and these are not going to be equally likely.  Both viewpoints involve randomness.

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on context, but *typically* the indistinguishable balls are treated as distinguishable for the purposes of distribution.  What is important is the implied process by which you accomplish the randomization, and the typical implied process for "randomly distributing balls (whether distinguishable or otherwise) into bins" is that you will arbitrarily take a ball and then randomly decide which bin it goes into.  You then repeat this, taking the next ball and randomly deciding which bin it goes into, repeating until all are distributed.  In that sense the balls *are* distinguishable... if not by certain physical characteristics then at least by the order in which they were placed into a bin.

It is certainly possible that the distribution process is different, but if so then it needs to be explicitly stated.  Absent any specifics, the one-by-one distribution method should be assumed.